# Case sensitive validation in Excel from Named List

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA in Excel 2003 to apply validation to apply validation to a given range of cells from a named list. The user can then select from a dropdown list of values.

Edit: Here's how I'm setting the validation, given a named range called 'MyLookupList'

```
        With validatedRange.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyLookupList"
            .ErrorMessage = "Invalid value. Select one from the dropdown list."
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
```

All that works fine, but the problem is that when validation is applied from a named list, it is case-insensitive. I.e. if a dropdown choice is "John Smith", then the user can type in "john smith" or "john SmiTh" into the validated cell and Excel will still treat it as a valid entry.

I know that manually creating a list via Tools-->Validation... will make the lookup validation case sensitive, but for my case this is just not feasible - I have to populate the named lists and assign validation programmatically.

Does anyone know of a way to ensure that Excel validation based on named lists is case-sensitive?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example on how you perform the validation?

Comment: I use VBA to assign the validation based on a named range - see the edit in the question above. The validation itself works fine, except that it's not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just build the validation list given the validation range (assuming it's not too large)

```
Dim sValidationList As String
Dim iRow As Integer

  'build comma-delimited list based on validation range
  With oValidationRange
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
      sValidationList = sValidationList & .Cells(iRow, 1) & ","
    Next
  End With

  'trim trailing comma   
  sValidationList = Left(sValidationList, Len(sValidationList) - 1)

  'apply validation to data input range
  With oDataRange.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=sValidationList
    .ErrorMessage = "Invalid value. Select one from the dropdown list."
    .InCellDropdown = True

  End With
```

Comment: This should work for small validation requirements, but probably not for the sheer amount of validation I have to do in this workbook. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Yup - it fails if the list is > 255 chars

Comment: Hehe, yeah - I have lists 100s of entries long. But a good approach for small stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal14.html

I haven't tested it and it's a bit more complicated but I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about StrComp? StrComp string comparison is case sensitive if you use vbBinaryCompare. For example:

```
   Set c = Range("MyLookupList").Find(Range("ValidateRange"), _
         LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If StrComp(c, Range("ValidateRange"), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            'Match '
            MsgBox "OK"
        Else
            MsgBox "Problem"
        End If
    End If
```