# Case sensitivity in Excel data validation with lists

Tags: excel

I might be overthinking the implementation in excel data validation.

Basically I would like to have "Data Validation" on the list to be case sensitive and I cant enter the comma separated values due to long list of texts.

What I would like to achieve is I.e., If I have Yes and No in the list then I would like to have something like EXACT(List A, List B) in the data validation. Please find the attached screenshot for clarification.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btpmu.png]

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360158/case-sensitive-validation-in-excel-from-named-list) may be of interest

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad I could not find the solution there